# Swing component in JavaFx swing node WRONG mouse events

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a small test a JButton in a SwingNode in a Stage, using Java 8.
Problem: right click is not triggered, the middle click is interpreted as right click ...
Here is the code:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {


HBox hb = new HBox();

SwingNode n = new SwingNode();

JButton b = new JButton("CLICK ME!!!");
b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()   {   
     public final void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    boolean isLeftClick = SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e);
    boolean isRightClick = SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e);
    if (isLeftClick)
       System.out.println("Left");
    if (isRightClick)
       System.out.println("Right");
        }
});  
n.setContent(b);
hb.getChildren().add(n);

Stage stage = new Stage();

Scene appScene = new Scene(hb,100, 100);

stage.setScene(appScene);


stage.show();
}
});
```

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish with the right click, besides printing?

Comment: I was testing some stuff when I discovered this issue. Long term, I have some components in swing that I plan to integrate with a fx application.

Comment: Still not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you want want to look into `isPopupTrigger()`. Different platforms have different popup triggers. `if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {do something}`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup)

Comment: This is a bug on java8, probably just on Beta. Reported on javafx jira RT-35953.